# Understanding JAVA code in external JAR libraries

Tags: java, jar, external, libraries

I've been provided some external JAR libraries for a project I'm doing. I can access the compiled code but I can't really understand it as its not in the form I'm used to seeing. Any tips on how to 'de-code' and understand what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: The bytecode was probably obfuscated, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Search the net for *Java Decompilers* (e.g. *JAD*). What you see in a jar is Java-Classes, i.e. the result of compiling .java files.

Answer (score 0):

There are decomiplers you can use them to de-compile .class to .java. We are using JD Java decompiler.

NOTE: I think De-compilation (or) modifying de-compiled code is illegal in some countries. Be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a decompiler like JAD to decompile from .class file to .java files, but in my experience its use is quite limited

Answer (score 0):

Try Java Decompiler (Yet another Fast Java decompiler) : http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ .

It can decompile your compiled library.

JAD is only supported up to 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a documentation and/or source jar that you can attach to your IDE, which will allow you to access the documentation.

If not, you have to decompile it.

Keep in mind that it might be ok to treat this jar as a black box.